# Glyphs vs FontLab, which one is easier and powerful for a beginner user?

Tags: osx, graphic-design, font

I'm graphics designer but I never thought about making my own font. I don't have any knowledge about those to software, and I'm trying to make an Arabic and English font. As I know, FontLab supports Arabic language in Mac and I'm trying to make fonts on Mac.

Can you please help by suggesting which one to start with for beginner?

Answer (score 2):

[Glyphs](https://glyphsapp.com/) is a great piece of software for beginners and very reasonably priced (I believe less than half the price of FontLab Studio). The interface is much easier to get to grips with and is much more "app-like". If you're a beginner in font design I would without a doubt recommend Glyphs over FontLab.

For most beginners [Glyphs Mini](https://glyphsapp.com/glyphs-mini) (which is a scaled back version of Glyphs and a fifth of the price!) is more than enough, but Glyphs Mini only supports simple scripts and not Arabic, so that may mean you want to go straight for the full version. You can however upgrade from from Mini to the full version for a reduced rate.

FontLab does have some features that aren't available in Glyphs like the autotrace feature. Broadly speaking though there isn't a huge difference in features—especially for someone starting out with font design.

In short—go with Glyphs. 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I only know glyphs but it's awesome...for a few years I don't know much about how you create your own Type but after I downloaded glyphs it was as easy as breath.... you can copy and paste your vector graphics out of Illustrator and export it like in Photoshop for example

Comment: so do you suggest it to a beginner user or no?

Comment: Yes if you're using Illustrator you will learn it very quickly because it feels familiar